# Why java is platform-independent, but c/c++ not?

Tags: java, c++

I heard a lot of times that one of most import advantages of java is platform-independancy. Thay say: "You can run java program everywhere if there JVM are". Ok, I got it, but why, for example, c/c++ less portable? I can run c/c++ program everywhere c/c++ compiler exists. Is JVM more easy to install?

Comment: well - you can give your customer the needed compiler along with your source - why not? ;)

Comment: Java has better marketing? And they forgot to tell you what compiler they used when building the JVM.

Comment: I say Assembler is the winner.

Comment: Two main reasons: 1) after compilation to bytecode, Java code is *still* platform independent 2) The libraries in Java are much more likely to be platform independent (2 is partly because of 1, but also because they all target the JVM and make no other assumptions about OS / hardware)

Comment: Because that's what the language designers decided when setting goalposts for the newly-designed languages: C++ was not written with cross-platform conformance in mind; it depends on platform-specific libraries and OS-provided APIs a lot. Java was engineered to have its own everything and the underlying, platform-specific JVM to take care of making any code work with underlying hardware. Of course reality never follows dreams of the designers...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it is definitely a real question, and it can be answered objectively. I still agree this might solicit comment wars (but it may do so even after closing).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I did see the review task complete. Maybe another one for the same question got into the queue?

Comment: I was referring to this task: http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/1510896

Comment: @JanDvorak: Thanks! Didn't know about that view. I was looking here: http://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=close&daterange=

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use the same binary without recompiling it - this is the point. You have to use a C/C++ compiler for the plattform (For example gcc/g++ or the MSVC compiler)

Take a look at Qt, it is a crossplattform framework, based on C++ - but you have to recompile. In Java you just create **[Bytecode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode)**

Comment: You still have to use a separate JVM for each host platform.

Comment: Yes, but this is because the JVM is based on C/C++ code and os dependent calls ? Or am I wrong ?

Comment: @BoPersson: Right. But *applications* can be delivered in binary form. So instead of recompiling all 18 apps you want to use (and hoping they've been written correctly to handle that, because there **are** massive platform-dependent differences), you install one JVM and just run the 18 binaries. (Note: I am **not** saying Java is better than C/C++ [or vice-versa]. I think it's a useless comparison. Wrenches are not better than screwdrivers.)

Comment: C++ applications can also be delivered in binary form. I hardly ever recompile Excel or Firefox.  :-)

Comment: @BoPersson: **One** binary form of the applications for all platforms is the point (as you very well knew).

Comment: @Albertus - You are right. If you could rewrite the JVM in Java, you would have solved the chicken-and-egg-problem.